# How to get xml document coming in xml tag and use it in the document

Tags: xml, xslt

Could you please help me to create an XSLT transformation that will take the XML document coming from an XML tag in the document?

The (probably erroneous) XML of my question looks like this:

```
<MESSAGE_XML>&lt;Name&gt;Milan&lt;Name/&gt;</MESSAGE_XML>
<abc>
  <Name>Milan</Name>
</abc>
```

And a picture of this (probably) erroneous XML snippet of this looks like this:

[image: picture of this can be retrieved here].

Thanks,

Milan

Comment: Please include all information directly in your post instead of linking to off-site resources that may disappear in the future or are blocked in corporate environments.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the input and what is the expected output? And what do you mean by "probably erroneous"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am only guessing here.

Given the following input:

**XML**

```
<MESSAGE_XML>&lt;Name&gt;Milan&lt;Name/&gt;</MESSAGE_XML>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/MESSAGE_XML">
    <abc>
      <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </abc>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abc><Name>Milan<Name/></abc>
```

provided that your processor supports [`disable-output-escaping`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#disable-output-escaping).